# String formatting a matrix

Tags: python, string, matrix

(For our purposes, a matrix is a list of lists, IE [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]. A row of the matrix is one sub-list.)

I want to make a function called format_matrix(M), where M any matrix the user enters. How can I use string formatting to display each row of the matrix on a new line? Also, every number in each row should have a buffer of 3-(number of characters in the number) spaces.

I want each number to take up 3 bytes, including any empty bytes left over. So, for example, the number "5" is 1 byte, so there should be 3 bytes - 1 bytes = 2 bytes of blank spaces in front of the number. IE "__5". Another example would be 53, which is 2 bytes. "_53". Or 234. "234". (The underscores here are used to represent spaces.)

Comment: What do you mean by `Also, every number in each row should have a buffer of 3-(number of characters in the number) spaces.` ? post your attempts.

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify it please, instead of putting it into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Python's string formatting?

```
In [1]: lst
Out[1]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 555, 6], [71, 8, 9]]

In [2]: for row in lst:
   ....:     print ' '.join(['{:3d}'.format(e) for e in row])
   ....:     
  1   2   3
  4 555   6
 71   8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_matrix(M):
    for row in M:
        row_str = ""
        for n in row:
            row_str += " " * (3 - len(str(n))) + str(n)
        print row_str

>>> m = [[1, 2, 3], [4 ,5 ,6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
>>> format_str(m)
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
  7  8  9
 10 11 12
```